# HTTPS configuration in JFrog artifactory

Tags: https, configuration, artifactory, appdomainsetup

I am using JFrog 7.17.x Artifactory version. I am accessing the JFrog console with `http://localhost:8082`. I have a domain configured for my environment (dev.sample.com). I would like to configure HTTPS and Domain setup for my JFrog Artifactory node to be accessible with https://dev.sample.com.

What are the configuration changes to be done to setup https and domain in JFrog Artifactory node 7.17.x?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible inside Artifactory. You must use external reverse proxy software like Apache or Nginx. Artifactory can only generate configuration files for them.